# Margin of software resellers

Tags: data-request, business, software, leak

I am looking for data about the typical margins taken by software resellers.

A software reseller takes a packaged software and sells them to their clients. Additional installation/integration services are typically additional fees.

The margin often comes with some restrictions, for instance to a particular geographical zone. It can be zero in some cases.

Margins are usually confidential, so any data would probably be leaked, or old/declassified.